# Update map with values from another map

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl

Let's assume that I have two maps of the same type and the set of keys of the second map is a subset of the keys of the first map. I want to update the first map values with values from the second map (only for the keys that the second map contains).

I have written a simple loop to do this, but I was wondering if there is a better way to write it using STL algorithms.

Code sample:

```
using PersonAgeMap = std::map<std::string, int>;

PersonAgeMap map1;
map1.insert(std::make_pair("John", 23));
map1.insert(std::make_pair("Liza", 19));
map1.insert(std::make_pair("Dad", 45));
map1.insert(std::make_pair("Granny", 77));

PersonAgeMap map2;
map2.insert(std::make_pair("John", 24));
map2.insert(std::make_pair("Liza", 20));

//simple cycle way
for (const auto& person: map2)
{
    map1[person.first] = person.second;
}

//is there some another way of doing this using STL algorithms???

for (const auto& person: map1)
{
    std::cout << person.first << " " << person.second << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
  Dad 45
  Granny 77
  John 24
  Liza 20
```

Comment: _"I have written a simple cycle for it but is there some better way to write it using STL algorithms?"_ It's a bit unclear what you're asking for. You should be aware that `map1[person.first] = person.second;` inserts values unconditionally, no matter if `map1[person.first]` was specified before.

Comment: As I have written that keys from map2 is a subset of keys from map1, in other words I have precondition that map1 contains all keys from map2 and I want to update values in map with values from map2 for these keys.

Comment: Have you checked the `map` interface for a range insert? Have you checked existing algorithms for something that could be used?

Comment: I can't think of anything simpler than what you have.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Range insert cant help me to update elements in map which is my case. I have checked algorithms and did not find something useful in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more readable to write `map1["John"] = 23;`
instead of `map1.insert(std::make_pair("John", 23));`? -- this would reduce work to "read" a significant portion of the code. I'd like to change that, but not without your approval :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no more clear and better way to do it than simple cycle.

Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 3):

This is not much shorter but could be more efficient when value is something more complex than `int`:

```
for( const auto &p : map2 ) {
    auto r = map1.emplace( p );
    if( !r.second ) r.first->second = p.second;
}
```

PS in comments you said that `map2` is a subset of `map1`, then your method probably the simplest and would not be less efficient than mine.

Comment: If map2 is not subset of map1 your code is better yep.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to merge them and keep elements from map2:

```
std::swap(map1, map2);
map1.insert(map2.begin(), map2.end());
```

Comment: It seems to work in a sense that map1 will contain proper values but decision seems less clear and intuitive than cycle and it also modifies map2. Still a possible variant though.